# How to create a repeatable POST request that contains multipart-form-data?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, google-http-client

I am trying to create a `POST` request that contains `multipart-form-data` that requires `NT Credentials`. The authentication request causes the `POST` to be resent and I get a unrepeatable entity exception.

I tried wrapping the `MultipartContent` entity that is produced with a `BufferedHttpEntity` but it throws `NullPointerExceptions`?

```
final GenericUrl sau = new GenericUrl(baseURI.resolve("Record"));
final MultipartContent c = new MultipartContent().setMediaType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).setBoundary("__END_OF_PART__");
final MultipartContent.Part p0 = new MultipartContent.Part(new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Disposition", format("form-data; name=\"%s\"", "RecordRecordType")), ByteArrayContent.fromString(null, "C_APP_BOX"));
final MultipartContent.Part p1 = new MultipartContent.Part(new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Disposition", format("form-data; name=\"%s\"", "RecordTitle")), ByteArrayContent.fromString(null, "JAVA_TEST"));
c.addPart(p0);
c.addPart(p1);
```

The documentation for `ByteArrayContent` says

> > Concrete implementation of AbstractInputStreamContent that generates repeatable input streams based on the contents of byte array.

Making all the *parts* repeatable does not solve the problem. Because this code
`System.out.println("c.retrySupported() = " + c.retrySupported());` outputs `c.retrySupported() = true`.

I found the following documentation:

> 1.1.4.1. Repeatable entities An entity can be repeatable, meaning its content can be read more than once. This is only possible with self
>   contained entities (like ByteArrayEntity or StringEntity)

I have now converted my `MultipartContent` to a `ByteArrayContent` with a `multi/part-form` media type by extracting the string contents and still get the same error!

But I still get the following exception when I try and call `request.execute()`.

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
```

#### So how do I go about convincing the `ApacheHttpTransport` to create a repeatable Entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to modify all the classes that inherited from `HttpContent` so that they would report back correctly with `.retrySupported()` so that the when the `ApacheHttpTransport` code was entered it would create repeatable content correctly.

The changes were made against version `1.20.0` because that is what I was using. I am submitting a pull request against `dev` branch `HEAD` so hopefully, this or some version of this will make it into the next release.

[Here are the modifications that need to be merged in.](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/compare/dev...jarrodhroberson:dev)

Answer (score 0):

If content length of all parts in multipart entity is known (returned as a non negative value) the entity will be treated as repeatable. The easiest way to make multipart entity repeatable is to make all its parts repeatable.

Comment: *1.1.4.1. Repeatable entities An entity can be repeatable, meaning its content can be read more than once. This is only possible with self contained entities (like ByteArrayEntity or StringEntity)*

Comment: ***Sigh*** I know what this paragraph says because I wrote it. See for your self:http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpmime/xref/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartFormEntity.html#61 http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpmime/xref/org/apache/http/entity/mime/AbstractMultipartForm.html#160

Comment: Your answer does not work, I was already supplying repeatable parts. After I found that caveat I changed serialized the `MultipartContent` to a `ByteArrayContent` with the `MulitpartContent` mediatype. Still get the same error. I have updated the question with all these details about what I have tried and why/how it is still failing.

Comment: If the library that sits on top of Apache HttpClient does not use its native MIME framework and simply passes a non-repeatable entity to it there is nothing HttpClient can do.